# react-full-page Module not found full page scroll

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll, fullpage.js

Please help I am trying to npm install react-full-page and use it it's not working I am doing 2 steps

`1. npm install react-full-page`

`2. import { FullPage, Slide } from 'react-full-page';`

and using code

```js
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { FullPage, Slide } from 'react-full-page';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
       <FullPage controls>
        <Slide>
          <h1>Inner slide content</h1>
        </Slide>
        <Slide>
          <h1>Another slide content</h1>
        </Slide>
      </FullPage>      
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

It's telling me this error V

[image: Error here]

Comment: are u using any bundler ?

Comment: only yarn and npm

Comment: You should read about how imports work in browsers. `import` feature in browser is mostly at earlier stages and since you are using a package installer, your installations would go to node_modules folder.. which is not usually acceissible from the client. You should use a bundler and then try to bundle it.. so it works in almost all browsers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

react-full-page is not working properly try @fullpage/react-fullpage it will work perfectly and do what you want to do

Comment: Yeah I also came to that ;)

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to determine the exact issue here, but my guess is that it has something to do with your node modules. Try deleting your `node_module` folder, as well as the lock-file, either `package-lock.json` or `yarn.lock` depending on what you are using. Then run `npm install` or `yarn install` to re-install all packages. Also, you mentioned above that you use both yarn and npm, which can cause some issues with package versions in the different package management systems. I recommend only using one of the tools.

Comment: I did all that about 10 times Ithink that it's react-full-page's issue :/